# Change height in through main.scss

Tags: html, css

There is a dropdown menu in our web app which height I would like to change. I looked at the source code I'm my Browser and was able to change it via hard coding. Now I would like to implement those changes in the real code. We have a main.scss file which stores all our styles. I created a style which should change the height, but it doesn't seem to work. I guess my CSS selector reference is wrong or something.

```
<div class="rf-au-lst-dcrtn ">
  <div class="rf-au-lst-scrl">
    <div id="test-main-form:account:name">
            
        <div class="rf-au-itm rf-au-opt rf-au-fnt rf-au-inp" style="width: 39px;"></div>
        <div class="rf-au-itm rf-au-opt rf-au-fnt rf-au-inp" style="width: 39px;"></div>
        <div class="rf-au-itm rf-au-opt rf-au-fnt rf-au-inp" style="width: 39px;"></div>
```

main.scss:

```
.rf-au-itm rf-au-opt rf-au-fnt rf-au-inp{
height: 18; }
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an error in your css syntax:

```css
.rf-au-itm rf-au-opt rf-au-fnt rf-au-inp{
height: 18; }
```

- a className should always be preceded by a '.'
- when you want to select an element having a set of classes `.clas1.class2`

So the proper syntax would be :

```css
.rf-au-itm.rf-au-opt.rf-au-fnt.rf-au-inp {
  height: 18px; /* added px, as it is required to specify the unit (unless the value is 0) */
}
```

To see possible selector in css : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp